# Recommender system model fitting on full interaction data

Tags: recommender-system

I've build a recommendation system using LightFM, which is a hybrid matrix factorisation model that handles implicit feedback/interactions. The interactions are website interactions (viewing a page, favoriting a page, buying a product, etc.) and the users are logged in, so the interactions are linked to a user.

I split my dataset by sorting the interactions on datetime and using the first 80% for training and the last 20% for testing.  Further, for hyperparameter tuning, I use about 10% of the top of the training data. I.e. basically using the oldest interactions for training and keeping the latest interactions for testing how well it generalizes to the newest interactions.

For recommendation systems though, I'm guessing you'd also like to also use the interactions in the test dataset, since those are items the user most recently interacted with and it seems silly to not train the final model using the complete interaction dataset.

Is this the typical approach to fitting recommendation models?  Do you do the initial hyperparameter optimization and then fit the model on the whole interaction dataset?  Or do you maybe fit it on the training dataset and run it for 1 epoch using just the interactions in the test dataset?  I'm not quite sure what's best practical heuristic to follow.